# When global minima does not exist

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

Can you explain why there is no local minima for the following function when $b \neq 0$:

$$
f(x,y) = ax^2 + by + c, \text{where}\ f:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R
$$

In this case a global minimum does not exist.

$f(x,y) = c$ is the local minima when $a > 0$ and $b = 0$.

This equation in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=extrema%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22GlobalExtremaCalculator%22%2C%20%22curvefunction%22%7D%20-%3E%22%28a%20x%20%5E2%20%2B%20b%20y%20%2B%20c%29%22)

Comment: What about $f(x) = x^2+x+1$, it has $b\neq0$ and has a global minimum.

Comment: @PhysMath Its $$f(\boldsymbol{w}) = a \color{red}{w_{1}^{2}} + b \color{blue}{w_{2}} + c$$ where $w_{1}, w_{2}$ are independent variables. And to the OP, a global minima doesn't exist when $b \ne 0$ because the conditions for a minima to exist $\nabla f = \boldsymbol{0}$ aren't satisfied. When $b = 0$, the problem reduces to a 1D quadratic whose minimum is clearly $c$ if $a > 0$.

Comment: Ah, I was responding to a previous edit.

Comment: @mattos Understood, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The gradient is $\nabla f(x,y) = (2ax, b)$.

I am going to make the function arbitrarily negative.  Take $x=0$ to simplify the problem.  Let $M<0$ be as negative a number as you want.

If $b>0$, you can increase $y$ to make the function as negative as desired by making $y$ negative. In particular, since $x=0$, $by+c <M$ can be achieved by taking $y < (M-c)/b$.

If $b<0$, you can decrease $y$ to make the function as negative as desired by making $y$ positive. In particular, since $x=0$, $by+c <M$ can be achieved by taking $y>(M-c)/b$.

So the function is unbounded below, so it has no global minimum when $b \neq 0$.